# Integrating Taylor Series with radius of convergence as the limits.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Imagine we have some Taylor series
$$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)} (a )\left(x-a\right)^{n}}{n!}$$
which converges when $\left|x-1\right|<1$. Assume it converges uniformly so we can interchange the sum and the integral. My question is what happens if we wish to evaluate the integral$$\int_{0}^{2}f\left(x\right)dx$$
I am asking this as technically the Taylor series is not valid for $x=2$ but only for $x<2$, so if we were to plug in $x=2$ would the integral diverge or would it work?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is $a=1$?

Comment: It can happen that the term-wise integrated series converges at the endpoints $x=0$, $2$.

Comment: @Gary how do we know whether or not it does?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, but this was just an example, so the values are not that important. I am more interested in how we know when it does and doesn't converge at the limits.

Comment: You have to check it via some convergence tests.

Comment: Computing $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0+} \int_\varepsilon ^{2-\varepsilon} f(x)\,dx$ should reveal whether or not the entire (potentially improper) integral converges or not.